# Хочу сделать систему выдачи и смены расписаний для уроков в telebot на python

Tags: python, база-данных, telebot

**Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, обладаю нулевыми знаниями работы с бд и datetime
хочу написать систему выдачи расписаний в боте при клике на "сегодня, завтра"**

**Главный файлик:**

```
import telebot
import markups as nav
import sqlite3
import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
conn = sqlite3.connect('ranchbase.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def table_val(user_id: int, user_name: str, user_surname: str, username: str):
    cursor.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
                   (user_id, user_name, user_surname, username))
    conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    text0 = 'Данный бот предназначен для расписания'
    text1 =' \nВыбери свой факультет из каталога:'

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text0, parse_mode='html')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text1, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.courseMenu)

    id = message.from_user.id
    sname = message.from_user.first_name
    suname = message.from_user.last_name
    usname = message.from_user.username

    table_val(user_id=id, user_name=sname, user_surname=suname, username=usname)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def content(message):
    text1 = 'Выберите курс:'
    text2 = 'Выберите факультет:'
    text3 = 'Выберите группу:'
    timetablemenu = 'Расписание:'

    #КУРСЫ:
    if message.text == '1 Курс':
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text3, reply_markup=nav.facultyonecourseMenu)
    if message.text == '2 Курс':
         bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text3, reply_markup=nav.facultytwocourseMenu)


    #ФАКУЛЬТЕТЫ
    if message.text == 'MT-S':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text1, reply_markup=nav.UnderfircourseMenu)
    if message.text == 'MTПП':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text1, reply_markup=nav.UnderfircourseMenu)
    if message.text == 'ИК-S':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text1, reply_markup=nav.UnderfircourseMenu)

    #ГРУППЫ
    if message.text == '2101-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2102-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2103-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2104-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2105-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2106-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2107-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2108-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2109-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2111-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2112-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2113-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2114-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2115-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2116-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2117-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2118-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2115-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    if message.text == '2101-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu2)
    if message.text == '2102-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu2)
    if message.text == '2103-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu2)
    if message.text == '2104-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu2)
    if message.text == '2105-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu2)
    if message.text == '2106-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu2)
    if message.text == '2107-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu2)
    if message.text == '2108-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, timetablemenu, parse_mode='html',
                         reply_markup=nav.timetableMenu)
    #НАЗАД
    if message.text == 'Назад в гл. меню':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text2, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.courseMenu)
    if message.text == 'Назад к курсам':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text1, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.UnderfircourseMenu)
    if message.text == 'Назад к группам-1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text3, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.facultyonecourseMenu)
    if message.text == 'Назад к группам-2':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text3, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=nav.facultytwocourseMenu)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

**Файлик с кнопками:**

```
from telebot import types

courseMenu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
courseMenu.row('MT-S')
courseMenu.row('MTПП')
courseMenu.row('ИК-S')
# courseMenu.row('4 КУРС')
# courseMenu.row('5 КУРС')


UnderfircourseMenu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
UnderfircourseMenu.row('1 Курс','2 Курс')
UnderfircourseMenu.row('Назад в гл. меню')


facultyonecourseMenu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2101-1', '2102-1')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2103-1','2104-1')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2105-1', '2106-1')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2107-1', '2108-1')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2109-1', '2110-1')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2111-1','2112-1' )
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2113-1', '2114-1')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2115-1','2116-1')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('2117-1','2118-1')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('Назад к курсам')
facultyonecourseMenu.row('Назад в гл. меню')


facultytwocourseMenu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
facultytwocourseMenu.row('2101-2', '2102-2')
facultytwocourseMenu.row('2103-2','2104-2')
facultytwocourseMenu.row('2105-2','2106-2' )
facultytwocourseMenu.row('2108-2')
facultytwocourseMenu.row('Назад к курсам')
facultytwocourseMenu.row('Назад в гл. меню')


timetableMenu = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
timetableMenu.row('Сегодня', 'Завтра')
timetableMenu.row('Эта неделя', 'След. неделя')
timetableMenu.row('Назад к группам-1')
timetableMenu.row('Назад в гл. меню')


timetableMenu2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
timetableMenu2.row('Сегодня', 'Завтра')
timetableMenu2.row('Эта неделя', 'След. неделя')
timetableMenu2.row('Назад к группам-2')
timetableMenu2.row('Назад в гл. меню')
```

**не могу определится работать ли с бд или с datetime**

Comment: Вы надеюсь не настоящий токен выложили?

Comment: не поможешь ( 
уже 3 дня думаю над этим (

Comment: Я по Дискорду только.